# Magento 2 - Custom block won't show in layout

Tags: magento2, module

I made a custom module to display store information like phone, address, etc.

I'm overriding the blank theme's `default.xml` layout with my theme in `\app\design\frontend\MyVendor\MyTheme\Magento_Theme\layout\override\base\default.xml` (which is working as far as I can tell), and inserting my custom block there (and it isn't being recognized). I also tried using a layout extension with my module in `\app\code\MyVendor\Custom\view\frontend\layout\default.xml` but that isn't being recognized either.

Here is my override default.xml file with my custom block:

```
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
        <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
        ...
        <block class="MyVendor\Custom\Block\Phone" name="custom.phone" template="MyVendor_Custom::phone.phtml"/>
        ...
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

The `phone.phtml` file is located in `\app\code\MyVendor\Custom\view\frontend\templates`. The code is just:

```
<p><?php echo $block->getPhoneNumber(); ?></p>
<p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p>
```

The `Phone.php file` is located in `\app\code\MyVendor\Custom\Block`. The code:

```
<?php

namespace MyVendor\Custom\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock;

class Phone extends AbstractBlock
{
    public function getPhoneNumber()
    {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/store_information/phone',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

The module is recognized and active. I guess the path to the `phone.phtml` template is wrong, but I can't figure out why!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the functionality that you want (rendering a template), your block class should extend `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` instead of the generic AbstractBlock.